# I can't resolve a sudoku with OptaPlanner

Tags: constraints, optaplanner, sudoku, constraint-programming

I love constraint programming. I've been studying and modeling in other frameworks and I recently discovered OptaPlanner. I thought I had mastered it because I was able to model a few problems, even with multiple entities, but I completely lost against the Sudoku problem.

First of all, I modeled the problem with a planning entity class 'Cell', and the planning solution class 'Board'.

```
@PlanningEntity
public class Cell {
    @PlanningId
    private Long id;
    private Long row;
    private Long column;
    private Long block;
    @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = "cellsRange")
    private Long value;
    @PlanningPin
    private boolean pinned;

    ...
}
```

```
@PlanningSolution
public class Board {
    @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
    private List<Cell> cells;
    @ProblemFactCollectionProperty
    @ValueRangeProvider(id = "cellsRange")
    private List<Long> numbers;
    @PlanningScore
    private HardSoftScore score;

    ...
}
```

Then, I wrote the constraints, which was perhaps the most challenging process.

```
public class SudokuConstraintProvider implements ConstraintProvider {

    @Override
    public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return new Constraint[] {
            correctRows(constraintFactory),
            correctColumns(constraintFactory),
            conflictingCellsInBlock(constraintFactory)
        };
    }

    Constraint conflictingCellsInBlock(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory
            .forEachUniquePair(Cell.class, Joiners.equal(Cell::getBlock))
            .filter((c1, c2) -> c1.getValue() == c2.getValue() && c1.getId() != c2.getId())
            .penalize("Value is repeated in the block", HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD);
    }

    Constraint correctRows(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory
            .forEachUniquePair(Cell.class, Joiners.equal(Cell::getRow))
            .filter((c1,c2) -> c1.getValue() == c2.getValue() && c1.getId() != c2.getId())
            .penalize("Conflicting value in row", HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD);
    }

    Constraint correctColumns(ConstraintFactory constraintFactory) {
        return constraintFactory
            .forEachUniquePair(Cell.class, Joiners.equal(Cell::getColumn))
            .filter((c1,c2) -> c1.getValue() == c2.getValue() && c1.getId() != c2.getId())
            .penalize("Conflicting value in column", HardSoftScore.ONE_HARD);
    }
}
```

At last, I created the main class, 'Sudoku', that inicialize the problem, the solver, and looks for a solution.

```
public class Sudoku {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SolverConfig solverConfig = SolverConfig.createFromXmlResource("scheduleSolverConfig.xml")
            .withSolutionClass(Board.class)
            .withEntityClasses(Cell.class)
            .withConstraintProviderClass(SudokuConstraintProvider.class);

        SolverFactory<Board> solverFactory = SolverFactory.create(solverConfig);
        Solver<Board> solver = solverFactory.buildSolver();

        Board solution = solver.solve(generateBoard());
        printSudokuBoard(solution);

        ScoreManager<Board, HardSoftScore> scoreManager = ScoreManager.create(solverFactory);
        System.out.println(scoreManager.explainScore(solution));
    }

    public static Board generateBoard() {
        Long[][] customProblem = {
            {8L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L},
            {0L, 0L, 3L, 6L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L},
            {0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 9L, 0L, 2L, 0L, 0L},
            {0L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 7L, 0L, 0L, 0L},
            {0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 5L, 7L, 0L, 0L},
            {0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 3L, 0L},
            {0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 6L, 8L},
            {0L, 0L, 8L, 5L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L},
            {0L, 9L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L}
        };

        List<Cell> cells = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
                int blockCol = j/3;
                int blockRow = i/3;
                Long blockId = (long) (blockRow * 10 + blockCol);
                if (customProblem[i][j] != 0L) {
                    cells.add(new Cell((long) i + 1 + j * 9, (long) i, (long) j, customProblem[i][j], blockId,  true));
                } else {
                    cells.add(new Cell((long) i + 1 + j * 9, (long) i, (long) j, customProblem[i][j], blockId,  false));
                }
            }
        }

        Long[] n = {1L,2L,3L,4L,5L,6L,7L,8L,9L};
        List<Long> numbers = new ArrayList<>(List.of(n));
        return new Board(cells, numbers);
    }

    ...
}
```

I tried several solver configurations: with and without construction heuristics; multiple phases, looking to divide the resolution; I made three custom moves, to change (or swap) values in an advantageous way; I let the solver run for minutes and days, I tried almost every local search algorith and I still have no feasible solution.

The best solution score I got is -2hard/0soft, but that try is not even close to the real solution.
Is there anything I'm not seeing?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Suduko, the Einstein Zebra puzzle, etc aren't good match for OptaPlanner/Timefold out-of-the-box. The default algorithm (Local Search) doesn't work well on those. Configure the solver to use an exhaustive search like [branch and bound](https://timefold.ai/docs/timefold-solver/latest/optimization-algorithms/optimization-algorithms#branchAndBound) instead.

Comment: @Agustin Cano I know nothing about OptaPlanner but I am sure that the solution is not in the code but in the algorithm.
A brute force Sudoku solver algorithm requires a stack to keep track of the return cells where it's decided that an entered digit is good or not.
In your code I do not see such a stack. Also the decision rules are incomplete.
Check out the dozens of sample codes in different languages that exist on this platform.

Comment: Thank you, @GeoffreyDeSmet! I will try using branch and bound. I would like to know the theory of why local search doesn't work on Sudoku but does work for the n-queens problem.

Answer (score -1):

Your implementation looks comprehensive, but debugging complex optimization problems can be challenging.

Certainly, let's consider a specific example to illustrate some of the suggestions:

Example: Adjusting Initial Solution Quality

```
public class Sudoku {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SolverConfig solverConfig = SolverConfig.createFromXmlResource("scheduleSolverConfig.xml")
            .withSolutionClass(Board.class)
            .withEntityClasses(Cell.class)
            .withConstraintProviderClass(SudokuConstraintProvider.class);

        // Experiment with different initialization strategies
        solverConfig.setConstructionHeuristicType(ConstructionHeuristicType.FIRST_FIT);

        // Rest of your code remains unchanged
        SolverFactory<Board> solverFactory = SolverFactory.create(solverConfig);
        Solver<Board> solver = solverFactory.buildSolver();

        Board solution = solver.solve(generateBoard());
        printSudokuBoard(solution);

        ScoreManager<Board, HardSoftScore> scoreManager = ScoreManager.create(solverFactory);
        System.out.println(scoreManager.explainScore(solution));
    }

    // Rest of your Sudoku class remains unchanged
}
```

In this example, I modified the initialization strategy using setConstructionHeuristicType. Try experimenting with different strategies like FIRST_FIT, FIRST_FIT_DECREASING, or others to observe the impact on the quality of the initial solution. Adjusting this aspect might influence the solver's ability to find better solutions during the search process. Remember to iterate and experiment with various configurations based on the specific characteristics of your problem.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).